# Can I close a validation dialog box with enter key but not submit textbox value but use enter for valid value?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a simple form with a qty textbox. I implemented some validation for minimum qty. If a user enters a number below min qty they get a dialog box stating they are under the minimum and I set the value back to min via an `onchange` event in the textbox.

If you use the mouse it works. The issue is when you hit the <kbd>enter</kbd> key to close the box it also submits the form. I am thinking because the cursor was in the textbox before validation.

I used a check in the form with an `onkeypress` event to check for the enter button so you can close the box and not submit the form, but I am thinking I may want this functionality for valid quantities or higher, less I force everyone to use the submit button. Is it possible to take the focus off of the text box when the dialog box fires so a user can press <kbd>enter</kbd> and not submit the form but then with a good value use the <kbd>enter</kbd> key?

```
function textQuantDown() {
    //Set min qauntity variable
    var min_quant = document.getElementById("min_quant");
    //set text box value varaible
    var elProd_quant = document.getElementById("prod_quant");
    var intProd_quant = (isNaN(elProd_quant.value) || elProd_quant.value.length < 1) ? 2 : elProd_quant.value;  
    if( parseInt(intProd_quant) < parseInt(min_quant.value)){
        alert( "Minimum quantity not reached");
        elProd_quant.value = min_quant.value;
    }else{
      elProd_quant.value = intProd_quant;}
    return false;
}

<input style="border:1px solid; font-size:14px; text-align:left;width:30px;" onchange="return textQuantDown();" name="add_id[1]"  id="prod_quant" size="3" type="text" value="#thisclickquant#"  class="popinp" maxlength="3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the rest of your code, you could have an event listener on submit, do `e.preventDefault()` and sub in whatever you want for the input values before manually submitting the form via JS.

Comment: I'm not sure on the implementation using e.preventDefault(). Would that still allow users with valid qty's to submit using the enter button. Could you give an example?

Comment: Basically, you would revalidate the input inside the event listener and then do $(e.target).submit() if it looks good. It'll hit your event listener again, but you validated the input in the last round, so it will pass through without infinite looping.